# Kivy Bing images layout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make something like a "Bing images" layout.

That is:

- Images are divided into several columns of the same width.
- All images are the same width.
- Images are added down in such a way that the images added first are
  at the top of the layout.
- Layout can be added to ScrollView to scroll with mousewheel

I did not find a way to do this using Stack Layout, so I decided to create my own layout.

I stopped here:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

KV = '''
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

ScrollView

    size_hint: (1, None)
    size: Window.size

    MyLayout
        id:my_l
        Button
            text:'1'
        Button
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 900
            text:'2'
        Button
            text:'3'
        Button
            text:'4'
        Button
            text:'5'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 900

<MyLayout>:
    #height: self.minimum_height

    cols: 3
    spacing: 10
    size_hint_y:None
    row_width: 300
'''

class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    cols = NumericProperty(3)
    row_width = NumericProperty(300)
    spacing = NumericProperty(0)

    def do_layout(self, *args):

        self.i = 0
        self.last_x = [self.height]*self.cols
        for child in self.children[::-1]:

            child.width = self.row_width

            if isinstance(child, Image):
                child.height = child.width / child.image_ratio

            child.size_hint_y= None
            child.size_hint_x= None

            self.i+=1
            if self.i == self.cols+1: self.i = 1


            child.x = self.x+(self.i-1)*(self.row_width+self.spacing)

            child.y = self.last_x[self.i-1]-child.height
            self.last_x[self.i-1]-=child.height+self.spacing



        def on_pos(self, *args):
            self.do_layout()

        def on_size(self, *args):
            self.do_layout()

        def add_widget(self, widget):
            super(SuperGrid, self).add_widget(widget)
            self.do_layout()

        def remove_widget(self, widget):
            super(SuperGrid, self).remove_widget(widget)
            self.do_layout()



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.add)

    def add(self, *args):

        name= list(args)[1]
        self.root.ids.my_l.add_widget(Image(source=name))

MyApp().run()
```

It is already partially working (you can run it and dragndrop some images from your folders to see what I'm about), but the problem is that I don't understand how to connect a ScrollView to it.

It looks like I need to add a line with something like `height: self.minimum_height` to KV string.
but it’s not clear where in layout class I need to calculate `minimum_height`.

How to make the code work with ScrollView?

Comment: What are all those buttons for? Should the images be arranged around those buttons? Sounds like a case for `GridLayout`.

Comment: Buttons are just for example.
Could you please try dragging several images into the app (and maybe delete these buttons from KV string), and it will become clear how the layout should work.

The main problem in my code is I do not know how to connect this layout to the scroll view layout so that I can scroll images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate the `height` of your `MyLayout` instance. In your `kv` file add:

```
size_hint: (1, None)
```

in your `MyLayout` section

Then, in the `do_layout` method, calculate the `height` of your `MyLayout`. Do a `self.height =` just once at the end `do_layout` (to avoid infinite loop due to `on_size` method). For example here is a modified version of your `do_layout`:

```
def do_layout(self, *args):

    self.i = 0
    col_heights = [0] * self.cols    # keeps track of the height of each column
    self.last_x = [self.height]*self.cols
    for child in self.children[::-1]:

        child.width = self.row_width

        if isinstance(child, Image):
            child.height = child.width / child.image_ratio

        child.size_hint_y= None
        child.size_hint_x= None

        self.i+=1
        if self.i == self.cols+1:
            self.i = 1

        col_heights[self.i-1] += child.height + self.spacing
        child.x = self.x+(self.i-1)*(self.row_width+self.spacing)

        child.y = self.last_x[self.i-1]-child.height
        self.last_x[self.i-1]-=child.height+self.spacing

    if len(self.children) > 0:
        self.height = max(col_heights)
```

Comment: I tried self.height = self.last_x[self.i-1] at do_layout method end, this causes critical: too much iteration. Could you check it on your system? What's wrong? size_hint: (1, None) already using because I have size_hint_y:None.

Comment: I don't understand what your `self.last_x` array is, but the statement `self.height = self.last_x[self.i-1] ` sets the height to a negative number.  Setting `self.height` will trigger the `on_size` method whenever the size is different from the current size. Your statement triggers that `on_size` which calls `do_layout`, which calculates a different `self.height`, which triggers the `on_size` ... ad infinitum. I will add info to my answer above.

Comment: Also, the `size_hint_y: None` or `size_hint: (1, None)` must be directly under `MyLayout`, not under a `Button`.